# Safari - password / text-security prompt to keychain

Tags: php, html, forms, safari, keychain

I have a simple html form that sends its data via an ajax/post. The form contains a password input, and when the form is send the user gets a prompt to save password to keychain.

I tried to change `type='password'` to `type='text'` and add CSS (text-security) but Safari still interpret the field as a password and try it to save to keychain.

It is possible to block the prompt to save to keychain ?

Version Safari: 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4)

OSX: 10.14.4

Thanks,
Filip

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528368/how-does-safari-know-when-to-prompt-user-to-save-password?rq=1) naming a field 'username' could also trigger the detection. Try to name your fields without using 'username' or 'password'.

Another option is to tell Safari never to remember passwords for your site.