# Get browser to remember username and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs4

I have created a login form using Ext JS 4 that has a Ruby on Rails application on the back end.

I want to use the default 'remember password' feature of the user's browser to prompt the user to save their username and password upon logging in.

How can I make the user's browser provide the user with this option?

Comment: Post your code of the login form. Typically, this is a browser feature and your code would need to conform to how the browser will prompt this. Usually, it is an input field with the name `password`.

Comment: There are some good answers in this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398763/how-does-browser-know-when-to-prompt-user-to-save-password

Comment: I think issue is with Form created with ExtJS, i am using 'Ext.Form.Panel' to create Login page. This does not add any form tag into html. Thus, not able to trigger the event