# Proper HTML markup and authentication flow for password manager compatibility?

Tags: html, angularjs, authentication, passwords, lastpass

I'm working on a webapp written in angular that seems to have trouble interacting with the various password managers (Dashlane, LastPass, etc) that are out there. Are there any guidelines around HTML markup and authentication flow to ensure compatibility? This is not just for login flow, but also includes things like password reset, user name changes, and so on.

Comment: Posted my findings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911864/angular-forms-and-password-managers/53956890#53956890

Answer (score 2):

It appears that [this question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413646/how-can-i-write-my-html-login-form-to-explicitly-enable-lastpass), but not in the context of AngularJS.

From https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=3385

> While LastPass can work on most website logins, if you are developing your own site you can help make it LastPass-compatible by using a simple form submit with a username, password, and submit field.
>
> Here's an example:

```
<form action="https://mypage.com/blah" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
</form>
```

> As far as what to avoid -- always create the form on page load, even if you hide and show it to people clicking log in, it's better to be there on page load.  Avoid ajax for logging in and avoid method=GET

So besides giving `name` attributes to your controls, LastPass recommends having the login form markup already in the HTML when it is first loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that question too. However I didn't see anything about password resets and user name changes, which is where I'm struggling the most.

Comment: OP states Angular, and this form is not an Angular form. Struggling as well on the same issue. @GregM , did you ever find a proper solution? It's kind of crazy that such basic stuff is so hard to get right, I'm sure some people have already figured it out!

Comment: Posted my findings here, if someones googles here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911864/angular-forms-and-password-managers/53956890#53956890