# How can I get browsers to prompt user to save submitted username/password?

Tags: html, forms, authentication

I've reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398763/how-does-browser-know-when-to-prompt-user-to-save-password) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password), but they work for me. Those posts are 4-5 years old, so perhaps the browser rules for this have changed or gotten more specific?

Here is the form for login. There is no ajax and no javascript of any kind. I've tried changing the the input name from `usernameOrEmailAddress` to `username` and that doesn't change anything.

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="login-check.php" autocomplete="on">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Username or Email Address</th>
            <td><input autofocus type="text" name="usernameOrEmailAddress" value="" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Password</th>
            <td><input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" required title="Password"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class='row'>
        <input class="inputsubmit button" name="login" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Neither Chrome nor Firefox prompt to save the password for next time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you clearing your cookies/cache?

Comment: Those inputs need labels. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will do this automatically as long it can detect a username and a password field. Here is a picture on my computer when I just copy and pasted your code.
[image: The Forum Test]

If it doesn't work for you, clear your cache and cookies then attempt again. Also what browser(s) are you using?

Comment: Firefox 34.0  and Chrome 39.0.2171.95

Comment: I use Firefox 34.0.5 and Chrome 39.0.2171.95. I found out that chrome only offers to save the password once it detects a successful login I guess to help prevent saving incorrect usernames and passwords where as Firefox will ask on detection a valid forum has been detected and submitted.