# Change password form creates new user in browser password storage

Tags: html, forms, browser, passwords

I have a form for changing my users's passwords.

Chrome is correctly memorizing the user and password combination from the registration and login forms, but the change password form is creating a new user with no name and the new password.

How do I inform the browse this is a change?

Comment: I think we're gonna need a lot more details. Could you show some code?

Comment: It's a standard password reset form. The code is in Laravel and it's not very interesting. http://i.imgur.com/t65yLLJ.png -- All it does is ask for your password and the new password twice. The hidden user input is my attempt at telling the browser "we are changing the password for this user".

Comment: Right now, if I submit the form, it says "Do you want to remember the password for *no user*?"

Comment: Sorry I've never used Laravel before.

Comment: It has less to do with Laravel and more to do with submitting a standard HTML form with a password and having modern browsers recognize we are changing a record.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but HTML doesn't and can't handle submitting passwords like you're talking about. There's a lot more code behind what you're trying to accomplish and I'm assuming it's part of the Laravel framework.

Comment: It is not more complicated. I am trying to pass form data in such a way that the browser recognizes it as a change in existing stored passwords. This is not a trick question.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2700066/608781 shows that this worked with username and password.  try removing the username hidden field from your form.

Comment: Please provide an example with as little code and data as necessary to reproduce what you ask about. Next to that provide reference to existing Q&A material here on site that should or could have worked for you and explain why it didn't help you so it becomes clear how you question is different from existing material.

Comment: Not all browsers behave the same. Which browser(s) have you tested your (not shown) HTML code with?

Comment: Ah you're trying to get Chrome to save\store the password locally for the user correctly. I think a screenshot next time would have been much more useful because to me, it sounded like you were trying to save a new password to a database (i.e. "... the change password form is creating a new user with no name and the new password.")