# Chrome remembers postcode rather than Email/username

Tags: html

I am working on an MVC5 Web Application , I have a simple registration form containing Email , postcode and password. But when I register the chrome remembers the postcode and password rather than email and password; and next time when I try to enter email the postcodes appear as suggestions.

My markup for the form is as under:

I have edited the question and pasted the whole form. kindly suggest me what to do other than moving email and passwords up or down.

```
<div class="wrapper">   

<div class="closeBetaWrapp">
    <div class="simplePopup">               

        <div class="loginWrapp signupWrapp">
            <div class="iconCont"><img src="images/orchaIcon.png" alt="Orcha"></div>

            <form action="">
                <div class="formrow ">

                    <div class="leftCol">
                        <label for="Email">Email</label>
                        <input class="formField" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter your email address here" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="leftCol">
                        <label for="Pcode">Postcode</label>
                        <input class="formField" type="tel" name="Pcode" id="Pcode" placeholder="Enter postcode here" />
                    </div>  

                    <div class="leftCol">
                        <label>Year of Birth</label>
                        <select id="" class="dropdown">
                            <option>Choose your year of birth</option>
                            <option>1980</option>
                            <option>1981</option>
                            <option>1982</option>
                            <option>1983</option>
                            <option>1984</option>
                            <option>1985</option>
                            <option>1986</option>
                            <option>1987</option>
                            <option>1988</option>
                            <option>1989</option>
                            <option>1990</option>
                            <option>1991</option>
                            <option>1992</option>
                            <option>1993</option>
                            <option>1994</option>
                            <option>1995</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="leftCol">
                        <label>Gender</label>
                        <select id="" class="dropdown">
                            <option>Choose your year of birth</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="leftCol">
                        <label for="Password">Password</label>
                        <input class="formField" type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="Enter your password here" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="rightCol">
                        <label for="CPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input class="formField" type="password" name="CPassword" id="CPassword" placeholder="Enter password again" />
                    </div>  

                </div><!-- formrow -->
                <div class="formrow">
                    <div class="rightCol btnCol">
                        <input class="moreBtn" type="submit" value="Signup" />
                        <input class="moreBtn cnclBtn" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                    </div>  

                </div><!-- formrow -->
            </form>
        </div>



    </div>
</div><!-- closeBetaWrapp -->
```

Comment: Can you please post the full form code? from `<form>` to `</form>`. Also where is your password field, submit button?  I tried after adding a form element and a submit button. it worked fine.

Comment: I have edited the question and the whole form is pasted now

Answer (score 1):

Browsers detect passwords by form.elements[n].type == "password" and iterating through all the document. Then it detects the username field by searching backwards through form elements for the text field immediately before the password field.

So, In your case, It thinks your postcode as your username field and remembers this.

So, solution is to move the postcode field above the email field.

If even after moving, it doesn't work, delete previously saved postcode-password value from 'saved passwords' in chrome settings. Also delete any previously saved values by using down arrow key to select the suggestion and pressing shift + delete.

I got the information about how browsers detect username-password field [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403848/4040525) & [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/SZxksnnm4dc)

Comment: I can't do this because the design is such that password is the last field and the email is the first , in between there are a couple of drop downs..

Comment: Then I think there is no way because that's the way browsers detect username-password combination. Try your luck by changing email field type to `type="username"`. If you are lucky chrome may detect it as username. Otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: Changing `type` won't work. I just tested. Only way to do it is to move email field below postcode field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `autocomplete` attribute to tell the browser what the field contains. For example:

```
<input class="formField" autocomplete="postal-code" type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode" placeholder="Enter your postcode here" />
```

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill for more information.