# Manually set save credential preferences in input

Tags: php, jquery, html

First of all, I do apologize for poorly formed title, I have no idea how to put it. My question is how to override the default input elements chromium/chrome/firefox/et cetera take to save credentials; for some reason it keeps on choosing phone number : password. Code follows if it's of any help.

```
<input class="frm-1column-text frm-input" placeholder="" id="frm-username" name="frm-username" type="text" valid="username"/>
<input class="frm-1column-text frm-input" placeholder="" id="frm-phone" name="frm-phone" type="text" valid="phone"/>
<input class="frm-1column-text frm-input" id="frm-psw" name="frm-psw" type="password" valid="string0" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Just a snippet, but it is in such order, putting couple of options aside. Thanks in advance.

As for PHP, if this help, I'm only setting the session token after successful registration, so I highly doubt it has anything to do with it.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285994/manually-set-save-credential-preferences-in-input

Comment: You unfortunately copied wrong url, if you were trying to show me another thread.

Comment: This is a good explanation to your problem: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2398763](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398763/how-does-browser-know-when-to-prompt-user-to-save-password)