# How can I get Webkit and IE browsers to prompt to save passwords for login through AJAX request?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, authentication, passwords, webkit

I have an HTML page with a login form and a registration form inside of an overlay.  When the user submits either of these forms, an AJAX request is made back to the server.

If the registration or login is successful, then the user is logged in and certain parts of the page are updated.  If there is an issue with the login/registration credentials, then the user is asked to correct the error.

How do I get the browser to prompt the user to save or remember the username/password used for this scenario?

I was able to get Firefox to prompt the user and remember the password by following the answer here:
[How can I get browser to prompt to save password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password)

But this solution did not work in webkit browsers or IE.  Also, I tried adding the autocomplete attribute to the forms with value "on", but this also did not solve the problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: At the company I worked at, we solved this by embedding a hidden login form in every page's HTML that could be made visible upon request, thus preventing to load the form using Ajax. I have done a fair amount of searching and experimenting with this, and I don't believe there's an Ajax solution to this. I can imagine browsers prevent this due to security considerations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are going to be able to find a solution to this that works across all browsers in a timely manner and if you do it may be very brittle and could break after any browser update.

A more reliable and robust way of doing this could be to do it with your own code by building this functionality into your UI. This would probably even save you some time in the long run. You could have a "remember me" checkbox or a "remember me" popup that comes up after a successful login.

If the user opts to be remembered just write an encrypted cookie with their username which if detected will allow them to bypass login. Assuming SSL I don't see this route as being much less secure than trying to force the browser to do it as the information will be stored un-encrypted on most users computers either way.