# Remember values in ajax forms?

Tags: ajax, firefox, forms, authentication, browser

Is there a way to make Firefox or any other browsers remember values in ajax login forms?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking that you dont have password remember settings for the site in question set to "never". Some sites also disallow remembering passwords explicitly in their form tags. In such cases, if you really want the form to remember the login (Such as if you are testing the site and regularly log in using the same credentials), It may be possible to write a bookmarklet to remember the details for you. (You could save the bookmarklet in your bookmarklets toolbar)