# Browser doesnt prompt for save password

Tags: browser, passwords

A client needs the browser to prompt to save the password for the login form. Here is the url
http://www.800promotion.com/userLoginPopup.htm

You can use the following credentials to login, Username: test1@gmail.com with the password: company. No matter what options I try the browser doesnt prompt me or anybody for the save password option.

Comment: What browser? IE? Firefox? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old one, but.. JJ, you can affect browser behaviour. Most likely user had ajax-login. Browser didn't reqonize login event.

for example there's some solutions: 
[How can I get browser to prompt to save password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password)