# How do tell a browser not to offer to save an incorrect password?

Tags: html, security, browser

Often on a website, if I enter the wrong password by mistake, I get a page back that indicates the wrong credentials, but Chrome (Or whatever) prompts me with "Would you like to remember this password?"

Is there any way to hint to the browser that now is not the time to ask, so that it only prompts if the user enters a correct password?

Comment: Note that a site should never say 'you entered the wrong password'. For security reasons (and logic) you should merely state "username or password is incorrect".

Comment: Saw that title and was like "there's a good candidate to migrate to [ux.se]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [JQuery & Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to post the login form to the server and recieve a response back without ever reloading the page, thus avoiding this problem altogether.

**EDIT**

Something along the lines of this (untested):

```
<div id="error"></div>
<form id="loginForm" method="post">
  <input type="username" name="username" id="username">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<script>
  $(function(){
   $('#loginForm').submit(function(){
     // Ajax to check username/pass
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST"
    , url: "/login"
    , data: {
        username: $('#username').val()
      , password: $('#password').val()
      }
    , success: function(response) {
        if(response == 'OK'){
          $('#loginForm').submit()
        } else {
          $('#error').html('Invalid username or password')
        }
      }
   })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: In that case, wouldn't I then lose the prompt on the correct password?

Comment: but does the browser still ask you to remember it?

Comment: once a correct password is confirmed you can then submit the actual form the normal way...

Comment: Aha! Neat. Could you roll that into the answer? It sounds like a winner

Comment: You might need to add the line `event.preventDefault();` and change `.submit(function(){` to `.submit(function(event){` so the form doesn't submit unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

No. The browser displays the message at the moment the form is submitted. It doesn't wait for the server's response, so there's no way to tell wether or not the password is correct.

Slightly related:

- [How can I get browser to prompt to save password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329)
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox%3aPassword_Manager_Debugging