# When sign up Chrome saved phone number instead of e-mail

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser, credentials

In my case. I have login form for sign up the form has some field like phone-number, e-mail address, password etc.. after sign up when the user want to login the requirement is e-mail address and password. Chrome automatically filled the fields password field is ok but in the e-mail field automatically phone number pasted.

How do i configure this ?

The shots shows chrome credential when i sign up the site.
[image]

Last one is true i want to saved like last one.

Form markup, that's the form phone and e-mail inputs code

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "SSTinputTextE input", placeholder = "E-POSTA ADRESİ" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "display:none" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone, new { @class = "SSTinputTextE input txtNumeric", placeholder = "CEP TELEFONU", maxlength = "11" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger ", @style = "display:none" })
```

[image]

Comment: Please add markup of your login form.

Comment: Also please review [How can I get browser to prompt to save password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password)

Comment: can it be interested about sorting of login form. Example password's input type is password so its saved as right but before password i have phone number as a text input type maybe the browser saved phone number because of it. when it was work clear. i didnt have phone number field and before password input type had e-mail that's why i am thought it

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem in a .Net MVC site with very similar markup. I also use `placeholder` attributes on the `input` element itself, instead of `label` elements before the element—just like the op.

I fixed the problem by moving the phone number field *before* the email field in the HTML (and form visually, if that matters).

I didn't dig into it enough to figure out the exact reason for this definitively, but I suspect it was because it was picking up the first `input` field *after* anything with the word "email" in it. Since there wasn't a label for the phone number to interrupt this logic, the phone number field was next so it chose that. I know Chrome uses some simple regex for picking up these auto save fields, so maybe its just not clever enough to realize that placeholders on the element itself can count too? (Again, this is just a guess at the reason. But my workaround above worked anyway.)