# HTML Save Password IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

i have a webpage and in Chrome and Firefox the browser ask me to save the login-information. But the IE11 is not asking to save the login-information.
Can someone help? Thanks!

Input for username:

```
<input id="mui-id-2" style="font: inherit; padding: 0px; border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); margin-top: 14px; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; font-size-adjust: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; background-color: transparent; tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" type="text" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.0.5.1.0.$=10.0.1.2">
```

Input for password:

```
<input id="mui-id-3" style="font: inherit; padding: 0px; border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); margin-top: 14px; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; font-size-adjust: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; background-color: transparent; tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" type="password" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.0.5.1.0.$=10.0.3.2">
```

Comment: You should really use style sheets.

Comment: This is a default behaviour of the browser which you can configure by editing settings

Comment: Use stylesheets except of inline styles. And give your input values names. I doubt it works without having names.

Comment: Did you check your browser's settings? Try it with some other site first.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Name attribute to your inputs.

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

Comment: Why should OP try that? This is really unrelated to OPs question

Comment: So that the browser can identify it as a login.

Comment: Read again _the browser ask me to save the login-information_ so it already does

Comment: Yes, Firefox and Chrome does. Different browsers work in different ways. Some only need a `type="password"` to understand that it's a login.

Comment: How are you sending the request? Do you post it with submit?

Comment: with an ajax request

Comment: Then take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password