# Google Chrome didn't remember login credentials in my login form

Tags: html, google-chrome, laravel-5, vue.js

**What I have:** Im developing in Laravel 5.3 and calling an API with vue.js. The workaround is I submit the form with vue.js, make a call to the API and returned a token if all ok.

**Problem:** Google Chrome dont remember my login credentials after an sucessfull login (Edge, Firefox and Safari yes).

**What I try:** Like I have seen in other questions in StackOverflow (Mostly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password)), I have put a name attribute to the tags (Even if I use email instead of username). Don't use prevent of vue.js. Do all the login and finish with an .submit(); No one works in Chrome.

**My code:**

```
<form id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal m-t-20" v-on:submit.prevent="login" action="{{secure_url('/')}}" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="error col-xs-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input name="username" class="form-control" v-model="email" type="text" required="" placeholder="{{Lang::get('general.email')}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" v-model="password" type="password" required="" placeholder="{{Lang::get('general.password')}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">{{Lang::get('general.logIn')}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you probably missing either **field name** or **field ID**

To be sure that it will work in all browsers be sure to provide both, even if name should be enough.

If your code is correct, make sure that you **initialize your v-model variables**.

Also, you should not use **form** while using Vue as you do not need input data bundled into the form as Vue model is handling that.