# Browser not prompting to save password, what's wrong with the login code

Tags: php, browser, authentication, passwords

I'm running some "Would you like to save password for this site" tests, so I created a simple PHP code that does a SESSION login.

The following code works, but none of Firefox, Safari, IE8 or Chrome prompts me to save password for this website, any ideas?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset ($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

if (isset ($_POST['user']) && $_POST['password'] == 'admin') {
    $_SESSION['user'] = 'ok';
}
?>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<a href="index.php?logout">logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user" value="admin">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: A similar question was already answered. Try the solution of this post: [How can i get browser to prompt to save password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password)

Comment: If you dont change the `user` on the form, you always get `value="admin"` so it will always show you the welcome

Comment: @RiggsFolly it actually compares password ...

Comment: Yes but `if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {` will always do the WELCOME

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Are you running this as `file:///` by any chance, rather than `http://localhost`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's a virtual machine, `http://ubuntu/login`