# How do I get browser to prompt to save password in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website that has a login page...

Here's the problem: the browser never offers the usual "Save this password? Yes / Never / Not Now" prompt that it does for other sites.

I tried wrapping the `<div>` in `<form>` tags with `"autocomplete='on'"` but that made no difference.

Is it possible to get the browser to offer to store the password without a major rework of my login flow?

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov no im not that **advanced** idek what ajax **is**

Comment: Try this one: https://www.labnol.org/software/force-browser-to-remember-passwords/28472/

Comment: You are welcome! Please upvote my answer then or tick green)

Answer (score 1):

Hi there Aaryan Khadka!

I'm pretty sure this is a browser configuration setting only. I am not aware of any way to control this programmatically.

For example, on Firefox it's under settings / logins and passwords
- ask to save logins and passwords for websites

On Chrome it's under settings / passwords 
- offer to save passwords
- auto sign-in

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put `type="password"` in `<input>`?

Here's your code:

```
<input type="password" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what you have tried out and what you are working with now.

Have you tried setting the password input as a password type? Take a look at this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password