# React Semantic UI Form, does not offer save password to the user after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using React Semantic UI, and I have simple Register Form. I want browser ask user `Do you want to save password for this website?` after *User* submits the form, because now when I send the form it just does my `sendLoginRequest` and after processing the requests that's it. I was trying to mark autoComplete etc. Nothing helped. How can I solve it?  Thanks.

```
sendLoginRequest = () => {
  ...
}
 render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Form onSubmit={this.sendLoginRequest}>
                    <Form.Input
                        required
                        label="Name"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        name="name"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        {...this.state.errors.name}
                    />
                    <Form.Input
                        required
                        label="Email"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        name="email"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        {...this.state.errors.email}
                    />

                    <Form.Input
                        required
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        autoComplete="new-password"
                        name="password"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        {...this.state.errors.password}
                    />
                    <Form.Input
                        autoComplete="new-password"
                        required
                        label="Repeat Password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Again Password"
                        name="repeatPassword"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        {...this.state.errors.repeatPassword}
                    />
                    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
                <Spinner visible={this.state.spinner} />
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it in different browser?

Comment: @HeisAif, no I have not. I am using Chrome, I need this properly work on Chrome since a lot uses it.

Comment: You need to check it in other browser so it can be determined if the problem is in chrome only.

Comment: @HeisAif, no It does not work in firefox as well.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/2382329/4901118