# How to make submit form which goes to the same page in Joomla

Tags: module, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am making form with submit button in Joomla custom HTML and I would like to stay on the same page after I click on the submit button.

Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using one of the form extensions? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the form action attribute out. This will post back to the same page. Have a look at this question and answer: [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action="")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/blank-html-form-action-posting-back-to-self)

Answer (score 0):

If "stay on the page" means that the page will not reload, or anoter page will be loaded, yes, thats quite possible. I think the best way of doing this is replacing the `<input type=submit>` with a `<button>`, which calls a javascript function that evaluates the form, submits the data via ajax, and notifies the user that the form was successfully submitted.

Comment: I would like to reload page. Is this possible?