# form action in page.tpl

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

dear all my script is such that i have to submit it every 60 seconds so i have put this code in my page.tpl.php file but that is included in some files and it cant  be executed alone .

so in below code what should i give the form action value. i have given self but self will go to page.tpl.php. inpite of everything is correct i am not getting anything entered in mysql .

please tell how to do . i cant call this page seperately as all variables need to be defined once again .please help

```
<?php 
    $res = mysql_query("select * from `".tb()."accounts` where id='{$client['id']}'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $Time = $row['Time_Spent'];
    mysql_query ("insert into ".tb()."accounts(Time_Spent) values ('{$Time}') where uid='{$client['id']}'  ");

    echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
        <p>Total Earning: <input name="Time_Spent"  value="'.$Time.'" id="Time_Spent" type="text" size="7"  /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />    
        </form>'
?>
```

Comment: please tell how to accept i dont know i am new here

Comment: Click the grey arrow of an answer if it is correct.

Comment: @ PLEASE TELL WHERE IS THE GREY ARROW ???

Comment: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer."

Answer (score 0):

Leave the action blank or use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. This is the page currently shown in the browser.

Comment: @ jens no if i ll leave it blank it will go to page.tpl.php which cant be executed alone

Comment: Hurray thats pretty weird: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/blank-html-form-action-posting-back-to-self