# Ctrl+S Triggers Function but only if inside of specific Text Area JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger a javascript function (an Ajax Post save function) when someone presses ctrl + s.

But only when they editing a specific textarea (with a unique ID)

So if they aren't "focused" on the text area Ctrl+s should behave like default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of similar questions:

- [Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)
- [CTRL + S to submit form and all inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205184/ctrl-s-to-submit-form-and-all-inputs)

I bet that first one will get you well on your way to coming up with a solution. Just replace `$(window)` in the sample code [in the accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery/93836#93836) with `$('#yourtextareaid')`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I thought I saw similar code to that before and it didn't work the other time.  But it works now.