# KeyPress Event C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, device, keypress

I've got a "Home" screen with 9 buttons. All text properties for the buttons are set like: &Returns so that the R is underlined in the display.

So when I press R at home screen I want the Returns screen to load. This is what I have:

```
private void frmHome_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.R)
    {
        frmReturns R = new frmReturns(empid);
        R.Show();
        this.Hide();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

But that does absolutely nothing. Can someone please help?

Comment: How does it behave? Does the event fire at all? Does it fire and the If condition doesn't pass?

Comment: You should check all the other posts relating to this type of functionality. Like for example this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048748/how-to-set-hotkeys-for-a-winform

Comment: @dutzu doesn't even trigger the event.

Comment: Try hooking to a different event like Key_Down and make sure the form has Focus, otherwise the event will be triggered to another target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property of your form to `true`

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

otherwise the event of pressed key will be raised in some inner controls of form, not in the main form.

Also, your comparison is case sensitive. `e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.R` will only work for `R` but not for `r`.

```
if(char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar) == (char)Keys.R)
```

Comment: Thanks, just noticed I don't have the KeyPreview event. Developing a Device Application. I need a alternative.

Comment: @WernervandenHeever what Compact Framework version are you targeting?

Comment: @WernervandenHeever key preview is not an event. It is a property.

Comment: in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.80).aspx the supported platforms of KeyPreview: Windows CE, Windows Mobile for Pocket PC, Windows Mobile for Smartphone

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly k, my bad.. Property

Comment: So, do you have it? Because msdn says you should.

Comment: I do. And I did try it but didn't work. Not sure what my mistake was the first time I tried Keypreview but its working now. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is on a similar vein:
[CTRL + S to submit form and all inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205184/ctrl-s-to-submit-form-and-all-inputs)

I've done something similar to this and it does work. It might need more input, as you dont want to accidentally be typing hit r to have the page redirect somewhere before you have finished?