# Understanding Self Referencing forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to learn `Self Referencing Forms`. I have read that a `html` form embedded in a `php` script is a self referencing form. I am still unable to pick the concept. Almost all the forms that I see in `php` codes are built with `html`. Is there something more specific about Self Referencing forms then just `html` forms being embedded in `php` script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blank HTML form action (posting back to self)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/blank-html-form-action-posting-back-to-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean something like this:

```
<?php
if (count($_POST)) {
echo 'You have submitted the string: '.$_POST['string'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="string">
<button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

The empty action attribute causes the browser to submit it to the same URL as the one that is loaded. Via `count($_POST)` we check whether the form was submitted and act accordingly.

Comment: If you want to submit the form to the very same URL you may leave the action property empty. It's valid (x)html and you don't need to know the current URL.

Comment: @TimWolla: Can you please explain how does the form loops back again once a user clicks submit? Thanks

Comment: The explanation was given by @Maerlyn

Comment: You should use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` instead of `if (count($_POST))`.