# Php Submit to self returning source code

Tags: php, function, form-submit, self

I am trying to submit a php form to self but after submit the page returns the source code of the page and not the processed data.

I have a issset to check if the form has been submitted and then have functions on the same page to process the submitted data.

Here is the code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if ($_POST['name' == 'px']) {
            $pxValue = $_POST['value'];
            $value = convertToEm($pxValue); 
        }

        if ($_POST['name' == 'em']) {
            $emValue = $_POST['value'];
            $value = convertToPx($emValue); 
        }

        function convertToEm($value) {
            $base_font = 16;
            $em_value = $value / $base_font;
            return $em_value;

        }
    }
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="" id="converterPx" method="POST">
    <h3>Convert Pixels to Ems:</h3>
    <label>PX:</label>
    <input type="text" name="value" value="" />
    <?php echo 'Result:'. $value; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="px" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-px" />
</form>
```

Trying to get the form processed on the same page

Using the Browser Inspector, i see that the POST is submitted with values.

Any help with this would be great

Comment: are you forgetting the `<?php ?>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To make a self action in the same page use this in the form action $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**

//This is the exact answer code of your question

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){


    function convertToEm($value) {

            $base_font = 16;
            $px_value = $value/$base_font;
        return  $px_value;
        }
        function convertToPx($value) {
            $base_font = 32;
            $em_value = $value/$base_font;
            return  $em_value;
        }

       if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type']=='px') {

            $pxValue = $_POST['value'];
        $value = convertToEm($pxValue); 

        }

        if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'em') {

            $emValue = $_POST['value'];
            $value = convertToPx($emValue); 

        }


    }

//form data

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" id="converterPx" method="POST">
    <h3>Convert Pixels to Ems:</h3>
    <label>PX:</label>
    <input type="text" name="value" />
    <?php echo 'Result:'.$value; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="px" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submit-px" />
</form>
```

Comment: if action="" is blank it will post to its self

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ,,but it is not the proper way of submitting data,,In php standard it should follow some coding styles

Answer (score 1):

If PHP source appears on the returned page it is either because you forgot the tags

Or because of the server not being configured to execute PHP correctly

(Or the file name has the wrong extension)

Comment: How would one check to see if my server is configured to execute PHP, i did a phpinfo() and it seems to work fine...?

Answer (score 1):

**This is a typo in your code ,,you used name instead of type**

```
if ($_POST['type']== 'px') {
        $pxValue = $_POST['value'];
        $value = convertToEm($pxValue); 
    }

    if ($_POST['type'] == 'em') {
        $emValue = $_POST['value'];
        $value = convertToPx($emValue); 
    }
```

Comment: @estern Check the recent answer by me , this is what exactly your ask for

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['name' == 'px']` should probably be `$_POST['name'] == 'px']` (with a similar change being made on the similar construct).

You are trying to use the result of the comparison between two strings (which will be false) as the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting the `<?php ?>` tags? also `$_POST['name' == 'px']` should be `$_POST['name'] == 'px'`, convertToPx function is missing, you have no param called name on your form annnnd your not echoing anything.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if ($_POST['name']== 'px') {
            $pxValue = $_POST['value'];
            $value = convertToEm($pxValue); 
        }

        if ($_POST['name'] == 'em') {
            $emValue = $_POST['value'];
            $value = convertToPx($emValue); 
        }

        function convertToEm($value) {
            $base_font = 16;
            $em_value = $value / $base_font;
            return $em_value;
        }
        function convertToPx($value) {
            $base_font = 32;
            $em_value = $value / $base_font;
            return $em_value;
        }


    echo $value;
    }
?>
```

Comment: yah i am aware that the function is missing i have only been testing the convertToPx form. Also are you sure there should be a second ] and it shouldn't be: $_POST['name'] == 'px'

Comment: I have the PHP tags too just didnt copy them to the code for here

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting to *self*, you're submitting to **nothing**:

`<form action="" id="converterPx" method="POST">`

**Edit:** As Lawrence has pointed out, one should avoid using the method I originally described below. Instead, use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];` and for more information, see http://www.webadminblog.com/index.php/2010/02/23/a-xss-vulnerability-in-almost-every-php-form-ive-ever-written/

**Original**: Depending on how you call the form, you can try:

`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" id="converterPx" method="POST">`

More details here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html

Comment: when i do this i get the url with this appended to it:  %3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER%5B'PHP_SELF'%5D%20?%3E

Comment: you should NEVER use `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>` within a form, this will enable XSS and XSRF better to just use `action=""` if posting to self...

Comment: Is your form generated by the same script that does the processing?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Fair enough (others, see http://www.webadminblog.com/index.php/2010/02/23/a-xss-vulnerability-in-almost-every-php-form-ive-ever-written/) but the point was that the `action=""` was blank.

Comment: by generate, it is just an html form in a php file that has the same processing function yes.

Comment: @msanford if `action=""` is blank it will post to its self

Comment: i dont need to worry about XSS an XSRF, wont be a public site

Comment: at first i had action="" and that is how i get the form to return just the source code

Comment: I learned something new today, I didn't realize that `action=""` was valid. Checked it out, and it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/blank-html-form-action-posting-back-to-self (Sorry, I know that doesn't help you. Maybe I'll come up with a brilliant idea for why your script is escaping itself over lunch.)