# How to properly protect form action attribute

Tags: php, forms, security, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action=“”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

I was told that it is unsafe to leave the form action attribute empty when using a form to submit data to the same page.

```
<form action="">
```

I am not really sure how something like this can be unsafe. What is the best method to submit data to the same page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: @Austin Thank you for sending me that post, it was informative but didn't really answer my question. That was talking about what the best practices were. I am wondering if it is a security issue.

Comment: What would make a security issue? It is only the url that your form is sent to... the worst someone can do is point it to post somewhere else, which they can do whether you define it or not. There is no possible security issue here.