# What does Action="#" mean?

Tags: asp.net, ajax-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action=“”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

I'm updating a project to include an Ajax Updater (http://ajaxuploader.com) and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working on my page but worked in my simple example. So I started pulling stuff off the page and found out it was the `Action="#"` in my form tag.

Unfortunately removing this removes other functionality (think it calls some existing Ajax but not quite sure). What I'm asking is: what is `Action="#"` and are there any alternatives I could try?

Comment: I've actually deleted my answer; your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a - specifically - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10314447/1073107. Note also the side effect of scrolling to the top after the post back has been completed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Action="#"` is basically the html equivalent of Post to self. # is technically an anchor so if you click on a link that is just `"#"` it does nothing.

Browser should interpret any `Action="#"` as `Action="THE_HOSTNAME/PAGE"`

Its designed to get around W3C Validation a times since `Action=""` is considered invalid, since all attributes must have values, this ensures a value is available for the attribute.