# HTML Form Tags, what is the actual default event or behavior?

Tags: html, forms, events

This really isn't per say an exact problem. But I have been curious, and trying to look it up to find out. Just for my own curiosity's sake. So what is the default behavior of a browser in the event that you don't supply a method? or don't supply an action either? Yes, I know from a syntax point of view its not correct. However I notice a lot of people now with AJAX being the in thing, skimping out on the normal form tag attributes, this is what lead my curiosity. What if someone without JS enabled happens across a site with a form, that has no method and maybe no action?

Is there something standard browsers do? Like attempt to get/post on the page your currently on? Or some other event/behavior. I know when I click a submit button in one of these events that the page appears to be reloading. But is it post/get, other? Nothing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [W3 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3), the default for method is the GET method. The action field is mandatory so if the browser does not know where to redirect the query, probably nothing will be send.

Comment: This is referencing an old standard.  HTML5 does not have the action field as mandatory. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fs-action

Comment: You can aso refer to this post [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1131781/1701063](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1131781/1701063)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the W3 standard is to reload/request the same URL if no form action is supplied.

I can confirm this is what the latest Firefox 15 is doing.