# JQuery Changing form url after submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have run into a strange problem, I am changing form url after form submission. I have changed form fields and they are changing perfectly but action url is not changing... Here is HTML code..

```
<form action="" method="post" id="payment-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="">
    ....
</form>
```

### JQuery Code

```
$.ajax({
    url: form_url,
    type: 'post',
    context:this,
    data: $("#payment-form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
            $('#payment_form').attr("action", data.url);
            $('#email').val(data.email);
            alert($("#payment-form").attr('action'));
            //$("#payment-form").submit();

        }
        else {
            $('#error').html(data.errors).addClass('error').fadeIn("slow").fadeOut(9000);
        }
    }
});
```

The alert shows me no url, why is that?

### Update

I have setup `$('#payment_form').attr("action", data.url);` it shows me no url but `alert(data.url)` shows me url.

Comment: what do you get when you log data.url? Also, you could target the form specifically in case "this" is no longer within scope

Comment: This isn't why you're having the issue, but it might be better to just leave out the action attribute in your markup and then set it once you have a url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: You are referring to '#payment_form' but the markup has an id of 'payment-form' (note underscore vs dash).

Comment: @brandwaffle You are a real guru! It worked with $(this) as well! Can you answer this so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: the cause of this is the empty action parameter in the markup. If you leave that out of the markup completely, the attribute can be set by jQuery when you get `data.url` back from the ajax call.

Comment: I actually left form url blank that was the reason it was not working. You answered this in your first comment.

Comment: Seriously? I totally thought I was way off base there...ok, updating.

Comment: I believe you that it's working, but I can't get the context as you have it in the ajax call to show the form (it's returning the window). Here's the fiddle...any ideas (i.e. maybe you're making the ajax call in another function call that's setting "this" to the form)? http://jsfiddle.net/eBADG/4/

Comment: For comparison, here's a working fiddle where I set the context to the form explicitly: http://jsfiddle.net/eBADG/6/

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$(this).attr("action", data.url);
```

to

```
$('#payment-form').attr("action", data.url);
```

Comment: @wode i was testing with this but it was not working. I have updated my code this does not change url. I have also updated my question.

Comment: @wonde Should probably update the id selector to #payment-form

Answer (score 0):

`this` within the success callback is not the form

Comment: I forgot to replace this with `$('#payment_form').attr("action", data.url);` this one is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an element with the ID `payment_form`:

```
$('#payment_form').attr("action", data.url);
```

Try this instead:

```
$('#payment-form').attr("action", data.url); // <--- notice the 'dash' instead of the underscore
```