# PHP form - Question mark within action attribute (action="?").

Tags: php, forms

The ex-programmer wrote this code: `action="?"`. I couldn't find any PHP script with it. Can anyone tell me what does the form call when submit? I guess it should be the `PHP_SELF`, but I am not sure.

```
<form action="?" method="POST" id="pa_form" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Comment: Is there any javascript that modifies the action?

Comment: Unless there is something that modifies the action, it will most back to itself.

Comment: Dont use PHP_SELF its XSS unsafe, if you want to post back to the form just leave it blank `action=""`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: Or you can omit the `action` attribute entirely and it will post back to itself by default.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that will cause the browser to send the form request to the current URL, but with an empty querystring.

IE: If you are currently on http://example.com/foo?bar=1 - the target form request will go to the URL "http://example.com/foo?"

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a self-reference. If it's in the same php script, it just means "self". Typically there are parameters after the question mark (`?id=5`), however in this case there are none.