# No need of CGI.script_name

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Please refer to the following code:

```
<cfform method="POST" action="#CGI.script_name#">
    <p>Enter your Name:&nbsp;
    <input name="name" type="text" hspace="30" maxlength="30">
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</cfform>
<cfscript>
    function HelloFriend(Name) {
        if (Name is "") WriteOutput("You forgot your name!");
        else WriteOutput("Hello " & name &"!");
        return "";
    }
    if (IsDefined("Form.submit")) HelloFriend(Form.name);
</cfscript>
```

Source: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UDFs_01.html#1167055

The code runs fine even without `CGI.script_name` attribute of action field. May I know why it's required then? The description says `"Uses the script_name CGI variable to post to this page without specifying a URL. "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default action of an HTML form is to submit to itself when no `action` is specified. See this related discussion on the topic: [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action="")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

I always include an `action`, if for no other reason, to avoid confusion.