# File extension added after form submit

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have a form on my website homepage: `www.mysite.com`

Now, the form tag looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
...
</form>
```

When that form submits, it does everything it's suppose to. But it also reloads the page with the full filename and extension. So the user will now find the URL in the address bar is: `www.mysite/index.php`

Is there a way to make the form fire to the same page without adding this extension?

There may be situations where the form is as an include in a footer, so I cann't be specific about the page the form needs to fire to, hense the `PHP_SELF` code.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do here. Are you trying to redirect the user to a different page after the form has been submitted?

Comment: try changing $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] maybe ?

Comment: @AmalMurali No, after the form submits, I want the user to still be on the same page.

Comment: PHP_SELF is evil as it allows for xss. Use SCRIPT_NAME instead.

Comment: @Christoph I see a lot of people say that, but I honestly don't understand why. Do you have a link to support your claim?

Comment: @Kolink I've got an german article that it describes pretty good. Basicly it's because you can add costum data behind the url like `/subdir/mypath.php/"></form><script></script><form additional/stuff/nonsense.php` (not urlencoded)

Comment: @Christoph But doesn't that still result in `/subdir/mypath.php`? `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` refers to the script that is being run, isn't that stripped of all stuff added to it? I can understand this would be a risk with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but surely this isn't a problem with `PHP_SELF`?

Comment: @Kolink that's the problem PHP_SELF doesn't strip this (at least under Apache as the author of http://blog.oncode.info/2008/05/07/php_self-ist-boese-potentielles-cross-site-scripting-xss/ states (maybe you can let google translate it)). SCRIPT_NAME strips it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` refers to the actual filename of the current script.

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

An empty `action` will post back to the current URL.

Comment: Ah right. I've heard somewhere that using an HTML base tag would screw this up though. Is that true?

Comment: I... have no idea. I don't think so, but I really can't say since I've never used `<base>` tags.

Comment: OK, it's just because I use base tag every now and then so didn't want a conflict. Nonetheless this will certainly work for my current project so I'll accept the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `action` to `#`:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
...
</form>
```

The `#` refers to the current page.

Comment: Is there a reason why a hashtag should be used instead of leaving it empty?

Comment: I really hate leaving things empty, personally, because it looks like an oversight, or like I meant to come back, whereas having a character there clearly shows that I intended it to be that way.

Comment: I found this discussion on the topic, anyone interested should at least give this a glance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: # actually refers to an ID on the page, but if it is blank it will end up being the top of the page. You can use it to link to a certain section of the page with #nameOfDOMId

Answer (score 1):

Try changing action to #,  this post to the current page.

Edit: Mike beat me to it.

Edit 2: It looks like you can leave out the action all together and it will default to the same page.

Edit 3: Mike beat me to that one too.