# PHP POST method doesn't send data to action="#"

Tags: php

I ran into a trouble yesterday and I don't know how to fix this problem.
I have a form

```
<form action="#" method="POST" target="_self">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and the .php code is simple:
      <  ?php
        if (isset($_POST['name']))
        echo $_POST['name'];
        ? >

the problem is that after I write something in the "name" field and click "submit" all I get is "
Notice: Undefined variable: n in G:\wamp\www......"
...but, if i change to  action="somefile.php" I get the result I need... it works...

Do you what the problem may be?

Comment: `#` means go to top of the page without refreshing, so your form will not submit for sure, if you want to submit to the same page use `action=""`

Comment: I read on this site that action="" is dangerous and should not be used. Is this correct ?

Comment: someone who wrote it has no clue

Comment: @ValiPloiesti: Read [Difference between action=“” and action=“#” in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720375/difference-between-action-and-action-in-html) and the link in the accepted answer.

Comment: @ValiPloiesti it has nothing to do with dangerous, `action=""` is same as `action="something.php"` don't believe everything you read, do some research... Some people have no clue as `Your Common Sense` said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change the action to

```
action=""
```

or remove it entirely, which will default to posting to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

action="your_page.php"

your_page.php is where to send the form-data when the form is submitted.

Possible values:
An absolute URL - points to another web site (like action="http://www.example.com/example.htm")
A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like action="example.htm")

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send something to "#"? If send something to the same page, I prefer use `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`, in additional if you want send something to the same page without refreshing, try using `AJAX`.