# Error uploading files PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to print the name of multiple files but `uploaded` array gives me nothing. What can I do?

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
        foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {
            if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "files/{$name}")) {
                $uploaded[] = $name;
            }
        }
        print_r($uploaded);
    }
?>

<!doctype html>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="post" encype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the `$_FILES` array?

Comment: Is your files array set? You may not be getting into your `if` statement

Comment: make sure that `$_FILES['file']['name']` exists, then make sure `$_FILES['file']['error'][$key]` exists as well, and that `move_uploaded_file` is returning `true`. One of those three things is not happening.

Comment: $_FILES is empty the problem is in the first if

Comment: Is there anything in `$_POST`?

Comment: No i don't think it is.  I think the problem is in the $_FILES['file'] because it is always empty.

Comment: Could it be a problem in name="file[]" multiple="multiple" ?

Comment: encype="multipart/form-data" shouldn't there be a t in there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typing error

Comment: I figured it out thanks and I am so sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend refactoring your code like this; note the addition of two [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) checks as well as an `$uploaded = array();` to init the `$uploaded` array before the loop:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
        $uploaded = array();
        if (array_key_exists('name', $_FILES['file'])) {
            foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {
                if(array_key_exists('error', $_FILES['file']) $_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "files/{$name}")) {
                    $uploaded[] = $name;
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($uploaded);
    }
?>
```

But I would also recommend doing a very basic debugging check right at the beginning of the code to see if `$_FILES` has anything in in:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';
    if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    …
```

But looking at your HTML file, your  `<form action=""` is empty:

```
<form action="" method="post" encype="multipart/form-data">
```

What happens if you change that to:

```
<form action="#" method="post" encype="multipart/form-data">
```

Or even [get rid of the `action` entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a):

```
<form method="post" encype="multipart/form-data">
```

I think that is the issue since your form is in HTML5 and the `action=""` is set, it’s never going to work. Specifically [as outlined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/association-of-controls-and-forms.html):

> The action and formaction content attributes, if specified, must have
> a value that is a valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces.

Comment: It was just a "t" missing in enctype="multipart/form-data"