# How to make value in form POST to same page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make everything happened on the same page. I have used `action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` here but it is not working. I have insert the PHP query below the form. Basically, my question is how do I make sure the form is posting the values on the same page. If it is updated, a pop up will come up.

```
$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$date = date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");

$query1 ="SELECT daily_limit FROM user WHERE user_id='$user_id'"; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $dailylimit=$row1['daily_limit'];
}               

$query2 = "SELECT SUM(debit) AS debited_today FROM transaction WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND date = CURRENT_DATE" ;
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die (msqli_error($link));
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $debited_today = $row2['debited_today'];
}
```

// form

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" > 
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <td class="alt">Existing Daily Limit</td> 
                <td>S$ <?php echo $dailylimit; ?> </td>
                <input type="hidden" name="dailylimit" value="<?php echo $dailylimit ?> "/>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td class="alt"><label for="newdailylimit">New Daily Limit</label></td>
                <td>$ <select name="newdailylimit">
                        <option value="100.00">100.00</option>
                        <option value="500.00">500.00</option>
                        <option value="1000.00">1000.00</option>
                        <option value=5000.00">5000.00</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alt">Amount Debited Today</td>
                <td>S$ <?php echo $debited_today; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alt">Amount Debited Left</td>
                <td>S$ <?php echo ($dailylimit - $debited_today); ?> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit "value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
```

// Values I need to POST

```
$dailylimit = $_POST['dailylimit'];
$newdailylimit = $_POST['newdailylimit'];

if ($dailylimit != $newdailylimit){
    $query = "UPDATE user SET daily_limit='$newdailylimit' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    echo "<script>alert('You have successfully updated your daily limit');</script>";
}
else if ($dailylimit == $newdailylimit){
    echo "<script>alert('You have selected the same daily limit as your previous one. Please choose a different one. ');</script>";
}
else{

}
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` included inside ALL your pages?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` to verify

Comment: While you're at it, do `var_dump($_SESSION);` and/or `var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']);`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, doesn't the form automatically submit to itself if you leave the `action` blank?

Comment: @Fred-ii-Yes, it is in ALL my pages

Comment: I tried using action=" " but it doesn't work. @KevinPei

Comment: Then you may need to wrap the code you're trying to execute using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}`

Comment: @user3210617 A good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a also if you do decided to use `$_SERVER`, make sure you do this `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` because it can be a security issue, if you don't.

Comment: @user3210617 what happens when you submit the form currently? Does the page refresh? Or do you get taken to another page?

Comment: @KevinPei nothing happens

Comment: Did you not try what I suggested above? @user3210617

Comment: See Arian's answer below about the submit button, being the most likely cause. @user3210617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I may have found out what the problem is:

You have a space after the word `submit` and no space before `value`.

This will prevent your form from submitting.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit "value="Submit"></input>
                              ---^ ^
```

Change this to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

The double quote might mess things up.

---

**Other things that are wrong but won't fix your problem**

Also

```
<option value=5000.00">5000.00</option>
```

should be

```
<option value="5000.00">5000.00</option>
```

Also

```
<input type="hidden" name="dailylimit" value="<?php echo $dailylimit ?> "/>
                                       // You have an extra space here ^
```

Which will change your `$dailylimit`, and append it with a space.

Comment: Having the `</input>` in `<input type="submit" name="submit "value="Submit"></input>` won't make a difference, but the `name="submit "` with the space like that "will".

Comment: Plus the space in `value="<?php echo $dailylimit ?> "/>` doesn't matter. Just so you know. I `+1` you btw. Because of the actual (most probable) cause being the submit button issue. `name="submit "` ;-) --- Good catch btw.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks! Yeah the last two suggestions won't fix his problem, but not fixing them may cause other problems later down the line.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, personally I think it's the submit button thing as you noted. I tried/tested with the OP's original code, and it didn't submit. Then when I noticed your answer, I knew that THAT was the most likely cause, I changed it to that, and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

make your action=''. it will post to itself.
then on top of your page check if the request is post ex. if($_POST){//add your code}else{//yourform}