# Getting Error 404 when I try it out

Tags: php, request

I made this `php` but I can't get it to work properly. When I type a name or a word I get the `Error 404`.

"Edit": Thanks i dont get the error 404 anymore but it still dont work when i type in a name. The text i type in and when i press enter it get erased and back to start. Anyone know if i missed something and how to fix it?

Code:

```
<?
     if(!isset($_REQUEST["name"])&&(!empty($_REQUEST["name"])))
     {
          echo "Hello".$_REQUEST["name"];
     }else
          echo "You have to type something!";
?>

<hr/>
<form method="post" action="<?=$_PHP_SELF?>">
     <input type="text" name="name"/>
</form>
```

Comment: <form method="post" action=""> or <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is vulnerable to xss attack.hence use `htmlspecialchars()` or `filter_input()`

Comment: On the other hand, leaving action empty does not conform to the HTML 4 RFC too.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<?=$_PHP_SELF?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

There is no such thing called `$_PHP_SELF` by default. Also, be careful, PHP short tags may be marked as deprecation in some PHP versions.

---

As mentioned by @krishna, using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` may lead to XSS attack. Use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape the URL.

On the other hand, leaving `action` attribute to empty does **not** conform to HTML 4 and 5 specification. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9678030/188331). If you think putting an actual URL to `action` attribute is troublesome, you may use `action="?"` or `action="."`, which works the same as `action=""`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: Watch out, they are different. e.g `www.example.com/script.php` is not equal to `www.example.com/script.php?id=123`

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` vulnerable to XSS attacks.So try to avoid it and use `htmlspecialchars()` or `filter_input` like this

`action="<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL) ?>"`

or

`action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>"`

instead of

`action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`

Comment: Good to point out that `PHP_SELF` is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Recommend to use `htmlspecialchars()` for older hosting environment as `filter_input()` is only introduced after PHP 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$_PHP_SELF` wrong.

Type instead:

```
<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below. I have changed the form action and also changed the following line from

```
!isset($_REQUEST["name"])
```

to

```
isset($_REQUEST["name"])
```

As effectively before you were checking the name wasn't set and wasn't empty.

```
<?
if(isset($_REQUEST["name"])&&(!empty($_REQUEST["name"])))
{
    echo "Hello ".$_REQUEST["name"];
}
else
{
  echo "You have to type something!";
}

?>
<hr/>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])&&(!empty($_REQUEST["name"])))
  // and you are not checking for submission
{
echo "Hello".$_REQUEST["name"];
}
else
echo "You have to type something!";
?>
<hr/>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />   // where is the submission ??
</form>
```