# $_GET is not passed in this form

Tags: jquery

First of all, I can't use the `action=''` attribute. That's why I use `on submit`.

Here my code:

```
<form class="search" role="search" method="get" onsubmit="window.location.href='home.php?m=search&q='; return false;">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher..." name="s">
</form>
```

How can I get my input content after my `onsubmit` url ?

Can jQuery could get this content and put it in this address ? How do do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: missing action attribute

Comment: c'mon @Ejay first thing he says "First of all, I can't use the action='' attribute. That's why I use on submit."

Comment: You miss the first line.

Comment: @13ruce1337 c'mon man whay can't he use that? If so how is he using alternative?

Comment: @JJPA ask him not me. I'm just staring at the problem thinking the only solution is to use an AJAX call. I think with the way he has it now the form doesn't get submitted to where he wants, he is just redirecting there.

Comment: For the record, if the form doesn't have an action, it uses the documents address effectively submitting the data to the page itself. [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action=“”)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

Comment: @13ruce1337 bI'm asking u bcoz there are rules You can point him to those you know it. its always about rules don't you think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want

```
window.location.href='home.php?m=search&q='+this.s.value; return false
```

Possibly even

```
window.location.href='home.php?m=search&q='+encodeURIComponent(this.s.value); return false
```

to be sure

To use the form action, you could do

```
onsubmit="this.action='home.php?m=search'"
```

and change name="s" to name="q"

Comment: "-1, not enough jQuery" :D

Comment: I mean to be fair, I don't see enough jquery in the question to warrant a response in jquery.