# Form action"" in cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp

Is it possible to create such a form:

```
<form id="xxx" method="post" action="">
```

via CakePHP:

```
echo $this->Form->create('xxx');
```

?

If it is, please, tell me how.

Comment: Does this not work? `echo $this->Form->create('xxx',array('action' => ''));`

Comment: According to: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html it doesn't.

Comment: Interesting, I'll play with some options as soon as I can get on my dev webserver.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10314447/804773 -- HTML5 doesn't like a blank action so there's a couple compatible workaround methods discussed there for you that I confirmed work just fine

Comment: That's not it. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->create(false, ['id' => 'xxx', 'url' => '/' . $this->params['url']['url']]);
```

should achieve what you need.

Though the question is why do you need action to be empty string? Setting action attribute as empty string would POST the form to current url and by default FormHelper::create() already set the action attribute to current url.

Comment: This statement: `<?php echo $form->create(false, ['id' => 'xxx', 'url' => '']);?>` redirects me to `/xxx/add`. I'm using cakephp 1.2. Maybe that's the problem. Also, it works if in my view I'm using <form> tak insted, but then I cannot validate errors.

Comment: Ah yes 1.2 was a bit silly in how it inferred and generated form urls. Try using `'url' => '/'. $this->params['url']['url']`.

Comment: `'url' => '/'` is an argument of create, and `$this->params['url']['url']` this should be placed below? If yes, it redirects me to main page.

Comment: Not below. `$this->params['url']['url']` is concatenated with '/'. I have updated my original answer and the wrapping in comments i causing confusion. Also in future please state your exact CakePHP version.