# Php delete row onclick

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi guys i have this problem.
I have a while loop that shows me the values ​​of a table. Now I need you may delete one of them, if it is wrong.
I just can not run this code , I do not understand what is wrong.
This is my php where i have the problem.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ))
{

echo "<tr>

  <td> ".$row['id']."</td>
  <td> ".$row['val1']."</td>

  <form action='' method='POST'>
  <input type='submit' name='delete' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>
  </form>
  </tr>";

}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){


$user  = $_POST['delete'];
$delet_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = '$user' ") or die(mysql_error());

if($delet_query) {
echo "Delete success!";

}
}
```

Why don't work? Thanks a lot man!
I need the user can delete the row.

Comment: Is there any kind of error that PHP show to you?

Comment: Your code seems to delete the row after showing the list. Put it before. And add a intval() around the $_POST['delete'] to prevent injection. Then, what is the error ?

Comment: @Spoke44 it doesn't matter where it is, because of the if statement

Comment: @bcesars When i click on the submit the query don't start, my website do anything

Comment: is the id field an int? maybe the apostrophes in your sql is throwing you off, have you tried to run the sql in a query window? are there any errros returned from mysql_error()?

Comment: No i don't receive any error. The form continue to do anything, but if i run the query on my database the query work. @DaveGoten

Comment: how I can do this ? @Spoke44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. There is no `<td>` before your form:

```
  <td> ".$row['val1']."</td>

      <----missing <td>
  <form action='' method='POST'>
  <input type='submit' name='delete' value='".$row['id']."' /></td>
```

So in technical terms, your forms are floating free soemwhere inside the table, within a row, but not within a cell.

Plus, your SQL is vulnerable to [injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to put your value in a hidden field instead of relying on the submit button's value:

```
echo "<tr>

        <td> ".$row['id']."</td>
        <td> ".$row['val1']."</td>

        <td>
            <form action='' method='POST'>
                <input type='hidden' name='delete' value='".$row['id']."' />
                <input type='submit' value='".$row['id']."' />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>";
```

Also notice that you were missing and opening `<td>`, and the corresponding closing `</td>` was out of place.

Comment: @Andreaphp have you stepped through to see if `$_POST['delete']` is getting set, if it includes the id, etc?

Comment: I have try to write a echo"test"; but i have see the submit don't enter never in the if(isset($_POST['delete'])){..} @mopo922

Comment: @Andreaphp maybe try removing the `action=''` as per this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: Don't work again, when i click the submit the page refresh and don't do anything @mopo922