# form action, blank or period?

Tags: forms, action

I wonder the difference between:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

and

```
<form method="post" action=".">
```

I have read [this interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a). It looks like blank action is handled by all browsers. Some say the *period* is not a good idea but they don't say why.
Furthermore, this thread is quite old now so i think it would be useful to have an update on the subject.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The blank represents that the result display of the form will display within the same page. Let say if you input the name, address, tel # etc.... and press the submit button. The collected information will display within the same page (probably below the form).  I usually do this when i design a form to make sure it works.  But there are various reason why they leave it blank instead putting  another target page.