# NodeJS not able to get token value from req.params.token

Tags: node.js, express, token, ejs

```
app.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({ 'local.resetPasswordToken' : req.params.token, 'local.resetPasswordExpires' : { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('resetMessage', req.params.token);
          return res.redirect('back');
        }
  ], function(err) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
}); 

app.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ 'local.resetPasswordToken': req.params.token, 'local.resetPasswordExpires' : { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('forgotMessage', req.params.token );
        return res.redirect('/forgot');
        }
        res.render('reset.ejs', { user: req.user, message: req.flash('resetMessage') });
    });
});



<!--Reset.ejs page ResetPassword FORM -->
<form action="/reset/:token" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newpassword">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Reset</button>
</form>
```

I able to get the token with req.params.token for the "post" after clicking 
http://localhost:8080/reset/fed831abf73150c96f6a3e392b5cbdcaccdeb9bd

Later when I submit through the reset.ejs for the "get" I couldn't retrieved any token value with req.params.token.

Any solution to it?

Comment: You don't pass the actual token into the form action.

Comment: The form action uses "/reset/:token" but I hope Tedd fills in the actual token here and not ":token".

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how should I write it in order to fill it there.

Comment: Did you open the browser's debugger and examine the actual GET request? That might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need another form with `method='get'` and `action='reset/' + tokenvar`. Also your async waterfall does not call done() so will not call the redirect if the user exists

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that the original code for this might have come from http://sahatyalkabov.com/how-to-implement-password-reset-in-nodejs/.  In this tut the jade templating engine is used and if you look at the reset.jade you will see that it starts with

form(method='POST')

but no action is defined.  I don't really know jade but in your example you are using ejs and in your code you are setting the action to

form action="/reset/:token" method="post"

and as everybody has pointed out the route that you post to is exactly /reset/:token.  So req.params will be :token and the reset will fail.  What you need to do is post the url exactly as it appears in the get request.  If you read

[Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action="")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

you can see that you can amend your reset.ejs page code to read

form action="" method="post"

Now the post should have an action equal to the get url with the token in place and the reset should occur.