# flask Cannot get the form submitted values

Tags: python, flask

I'm newbie to flask,I have such a form:

```
<form class="form" action={{ url_for('/login') }} method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="usename" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
```

I use `request.form()`and `request.form.get()` to get submitted values,but the result is always the same**"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -**

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    name=request.form['usename']
    password=request.form['password']
    form_data=request.form.get('usename')
    print name,password,form_data
    return render_template('login.html')
```

And I try visiting `/login` ,it shows **Bad Request**.But when it is modified to such,it's ok.It seems my `request` statement block is incorrect.

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: could you share the source of the rendered html page that your browser receives?
I have a feeling that `url_for` is not returning what it should.

Comment: I have solved it after I delete `script` statement block.It's my css file loading problem.

Comment: a problem in css file does not result in a BadRequest for the whole web page. generally.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of form action change the

```
action="{{url_for('index')}}"
```

Your form does not post actually and you are try to get values. And don't forget to add a view function named `index` or you can use instead `login` instead `index`

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are trying to get those values from `login.html` file. If it is so you have to use something like this

```
    @app.route('/login',methods = ['GET','POST'])
    def login():
         if request.method =='POST':
              name=request.form['usename']
              password=request.form['password']
              form_data=request.form.get('usename')
              print name,password,form_data
         return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: I try it,but the result is still **GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -**.

Comment: did you change the `{{ url_for('login') }}`

Answer (score 0):

try leaving the action field emtpy.

```
<form class="form" action="" method="POST">
```

leaving it empty will post to the same location where the form was downloaded from, which I guess is your use case here.

[1] [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action="")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)