# How can I keep the URL id on submit?

Tags: php, html

When I click submit, the data is submitted to the database but the URL id of the book disappears to ----`book.php`

I want the URL to go back to the id of the page e.g. ----book.php?id=3

Is it possible to keep the first line as `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` and add the `value="<?php echo $book_id ?>"`?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $book_id ?>" name="book_id" />
    <p>Author: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['author']; ?>" name="author" id="author" readonly /></p>
    <p>Summary: <input type="text" name="summary" value="<?php echo $summary;?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />    
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $book_id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: This isn't SQL question, but you have it tagged as such

Comment: you send your form with POST and try to read GET. you simply have to access $_POST. By the way, its better to use filter_input method than directly access to super globals.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
// save values in DB

header('Location: book.php?id=' . $book_id);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You send a POST form but are trying to retrieve a GET value. Additinally, the parameter is named `book_id`, not `id`.

Use `$book_id = $_POST['book_id'];`

`if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` also won't work, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyone of these:

`PHP_SELF` returns just URL. Use `REQUEST_URI` that returns URL with query string:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);?>">
```

<sup>[you can also omit action values - that will have same behavior]</sup>

or if you want just `id`, then use:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?id=" . $_GET['id'];?>">
```

---

**Note:** Use validation wherever necessary. I just gave you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no name with `"id"`

If you want to get the book id:

```
if (isset($_POST['book_id'])) {
    $book_id = $_POST['book_id'];
}
```

**OR** modify the HTML like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $book_id ?>" name="id" />

   <p>Author: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['author']; ?>" name="author" id="author" readonly />
   </p>

   <p>Summary: <input type="text" name="summary" value="<?php echo $summary;?>" /></p>

   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />    
</form>
```

On the other hand, if you have problems with POST, just modify the first line of HTML for this one:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?id=" . echo $book_id; ?>">
```

Comment: The error i get when i add in post: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: book_id Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0019258008{main}( )...\book.php:0 " name="book_id" /> for the line    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $book_id ?>" name="id" />

Comment: @Lily so you need to add modify the line of <form> for this:
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?id=" . echo $book_id; ?>">

Answer (score 0):

It is because **$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]** contains only URL . It does not contain get queries . To solve the problem leave your action empty

e.g

```
<form method="post" action="">.....
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrong parameter problem ? @syck

Comment: theres no parameter problem when i use this

Comment: It relies on having the browser send the old URI, if it does not see any action parameter content. That may be the case, or it may be truncated to the script name, or anything else. (We will see whether you still understand this problen half a year later. It is simply bad practice.) If `id` is communicated over the "old" URI, you can probably skip the `book_id` hidden tag.

Comment: Please refer to this question  @syck

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Comment: If I maay cite: _Note: This step is a willful violation of RFC 3986, which would require base URL processing here. This violation is motivated by a desire for compatibility with legacy content._

Comment: Yes. Leaving action empty will also make the form vulnerable to click jacking attack.