# Why does the post method not detect the submitted name?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 9x9 field. When I press **any** button, I want it to display the coordinates, but for some reason it doesn't.

Does someone know where it goes wrong? Am I doing something which is impossible?

Current code:

```php
<?php
echo "<iframe name='frame'></iframe>";
$aww_ar = array();
// SELECT PLAYING FIELD ValLUES
$th = 10;
$tw = 10;
// Amount of numbers
$amount = 5;
// Create 2d array
for ($y = 0;$y < $th;$y++) {
    for ($x = 0;$x < $tw;$x++) {
        $randomise = rand(1, $amount);
        $aww_ar[$x][$y] = $randomise;
    }
}

// create 2d table array
?>        
    <form method="post" target="frame" action="">
        <table>
        <?php
foreach ($aww_ar as $x => & $value) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($aww_ar[0] as $y => $v) {
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='" . $x . ',' . $y . "' value='" . $aww_ar[$x][$y] . "'></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST[$x . ',' . $y])) {
    echo $x . ',' . $y;
}
```

Comment: Names don't usually have commas in them. Try an underscore instead.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST[$x.','.$y])){` - `$x` and `$y` both have the value `9` at this point in your script, so this part would only work if you clicked the very last button you created, because only that one has the name `9,9`.

Comment: @aynber i've  just tried but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @04FS valid point, sadly even when pressed the 9,9 button it still doesn't work. Also when pressed the button, it updates the values (atleast that is what i think it does)

Comment: I would use the same name on all buttons, and put all the info you need to submit into the value - for example by sticking x, y and the random value into an array, and then encoding that as JSON. And the receiving end, you decode it again, and you have access to your three separate values again.

Comment: Maybe it's unrelated, but I'd remove the `action=""` altogether. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

Comment: @04FS Im not really familiar with JSON but ill give it a shot thanks for the help!

Comment: @devb every bit helps, thanks :)

Comment: As @04FS already commented, you're using the $x and $y values which are set after finishing the loop, so you're only checking 1 button, the last one. Loop over the possible values for $x and $y to find the value that was clicked.

Comment: you should simplify the `name=` attribute to: `name='$x,$y'`. Now when you click the very last button you'll get the 9,9 echoed.

Comment: @jibsteroos I changed the name to name='$x,$y' , But i still cant get it echoed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what the purpose of the iframe is. If you rename your fields to use underscore instead of comma, then the following code should print the value of the clicked button.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $value = $_POST['field'];
    echo $value;
}
    $aww_ar = array();

    // SELECT PLAYING FIELD ValLUES
    $th = 10;
    $tw = 10;

    // Amount of numbers
    $amount = 5;

    // Create 2d array
    for($y = 0; $y < $th; $y++){
        for($x = 0; $x < $tw; $x++){
            $randomise = rand(1,$amount);
            $aww_ar[$x][$y] = $randomise ;
        }
    }

    // create 2d table array
?>        
    <form method="post">
        <table>
        <?php
        foreach ($aww_ar as $x=>&$value) {
            echo"<tr>";
            foreach ($aww_ar[0] as $y=>$v) {
                echo "<td><input type='submit' name='field' value='".$aww_ar[$x][$y]."'></td>";
            }
            echo"</tr>";
        }
        ?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Note, the code assumes you will only have one variable in your post array.

Comment: The reason why im using an iframe is because i dont want all the numbers that have been automatically generated to reload when pressed 1 button.

Comment: Are you saying that on post action, you don't want to show the grid but just the value selected?

Comment: When you press on any button in the grid, i want the echo to be echoed out BUT without iframe the field would reload.

Comment: I've refactored your code such that on submit it does not show the grid but the value selected.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be working but ive only got 1 problem now, The value showing is good except, the grid goes away. I wanted the grid to stay.

Comment: Edited the code, the grid should stay now and show the selected value.

Comment: Almost perfect, the only but surely last problem is that when you press a button all the buttons are getting new values, the iframe i added prevented that from happening.