# Why do my PHP Delete button and functions only work firefox?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Hello fellow Stack Overflowers!

I have an issue with my my_admin.php file, my deletion buttons only process on firefox and no other browser, it's a tricky one, i thought it may have been my update to a new version of php but put back the original version and same issue :( If anyone can take a quick loot at my core code and see if they can spot an error. Code for my_admin is below. below that is pdocon.php and my functions.php all are included in the header of the my_admin.php file. Thanks anyone and everyone!

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>


<?php

//Include functions
include('includes/functions.php');

?>

<?php
/************** Fetching data from database using id ******************/

//require database class files
require('includes/pdocon.php');

//instatiating our database objects
$db = new Pdocon;

//Create a query to select all users to display in the table

$db->query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email=:email");

$email  =   $_SESSION['user_data']['email'];

$db->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//Fetch all data and keep in a result set
$row = $db->fetchSingle();

?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">My Account</h2>


    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-9">


            <?php showmsg(); ?>

            <?php if ($row) { ?>


                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name" style="color:#f3f3f3;">Fullname:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['fullname'] ?>" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email" style="color:#f3f3f3;">Email:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:#f3f3f3;">Password:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <fieldset disabled>
                                <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="yes" class="form-control disabled" id="pwd" value="<?php echo $row['password'] ?>" required>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit_admin.php?admin_id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Edit</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name="delete_form">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="edit_admin.php?admin_id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">

                <?php $image = $row['image']; ?>

                <?php echo ' <img src="uploaded_image/' . $image . '"  style="padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:30px;width:220px;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;">'; ?>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>






    <?php

    /************** Deleting data from database when delete button is clicked ******************/

    if (isset($_POST['delete_form'])) {

        $admin_id = $_SESSION['user_data']['id'];

        keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">

              <strong>Confirm!</strong> Do you want to delete your account? <br>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">No, Thanks</a><br>
              <form action="my_admin.php" method="post" action="my_admin.php">
              <input type="hidden" value="' . $admin_id . '" name="id"><br>
              <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Yes, Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
              </form>
            </div>');
    }



    //If the Yes Delete (confim delete) button is click from the closable div proceed to delete


    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $db->query('DELETE FROM admin WHERE id=:id');

        $db->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $run = $db->execute();

        if ($run) {
            redirect('logout.php');
        } else {

            keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                      <strong>Sorry </strong>User with ID ' . $id . ' Could not be deleted 
                </div>');
        }
    }

    ?>

    </div>

</div>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

pdocon.php

```
<?php
class Pdocon
{


    // The connection Properties


    //Localhost Db information
    private $host       = "localhost";
    private $user       = "root";
    private $pass       = "";
    private $dbnm       = "wm_app";

    //Online Db information
    private $host       = "localhost";
    private $user       = "whiteman_dbadmin";
    private $pass       = "dingleberries";
    private $dbnm       = "whiteman_wmdb"; 


    private $dbh;


    private $errmsg;

    //Statement Handler
    private $stmt;


    //Method to open our connection

    public function __construct()
    {

        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . "; dbname=" . $this->dbnm;

        $options = array(

            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,

            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

        );

        try {

            $this->dbh  = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);

            //echo "Successfully Connected";

        } catch (PDOException $error) {

            $this->errmsg = $error->getMessage();

            echo $this->errmsg;
        }
    }



    //Write query helper function using the stmt property
    public function query($query)
    {

        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }


    //Creating a bind function 
    public function bindvalue($param, $value, $type)
    {

        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }


    //Function to execute statement
    public function execute()
    {

        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }


    //Function to check if statement was successfully executed
    public function confirm_result()
    {

        $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    //Command to fetch data in a result set in associative array
    public function fetchMultiple()
    {

        $this->execute();

        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    //Command count fetched data in a result set 

    public function fetchSingle()
    {

        $this->execute();

        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

functions.php

```
<?php

//function to trim values
function cleandata($value)
{

    return trim($value);
}



//function to sanitize value for string
function sanitize($raw_value)
{

    return filter_var($raw_value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}



//function to validate value for email
function valemail($raw_email)
{

    return filter_var($raw_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

//function to validate value for integer
function valint($raw_int)
{

    return filter_var($raw_int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
}


//function to redirect
function redirect($page)
{

    header("Location: {$page}");
}


//function to keep error and success messages in a session 
function keepmsg($message)
{

    if (empty($message)) {

        $message = "";
    } else {

        $_SESSION['msg']    =   $message;
    }
}


//function to display the stored message in the session super global
function showmsg()
{

    if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {

        echo $_SESSION['msg'];

        unset($_SESSION['msg']);
    }
}


//Create function to hash password using md5
function hashpassword($clean_password)
{

    return md5($clean_password);
}
```

Comment: so, in other browser, you click the button. then what happen? show alert  or nothing

Comment: No Altert at all, the page does some quick partial refresh and then nothing, in firefox you click delete once it does nothing then you click in second time the confirm alert apears and click yes and the delete is processed. other browsers, chrome edge, edge-chronium all do nothing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good practice to use an empty URL for a HTML form's action attribute? (action="")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a)

Comment: thanks Johannes, unfortunatly it didnt improve the function, however i just discovered after clicking 20 times in a row it evetually shows up? so strange? ANd i can confirm the fuction does delete the admin, but only after roughly the 20th click?

Comment: I tried most approved options in the link, such as action="?" action="#" or removing it completely. but still takes 20 clicks?

Comment: `<button type="submit"` != `<input type="submit"`

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, just confirming the button could be set like this:

 <button type="submit" !=input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" name="delete_form">Delete</button> ?? Just tried that sorry to say no progress.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue by rearranging the if(isset) function to above the initial code and the delete function worked, also set the submit button type as submit. fixed own issue!